# How to compile ES6 to JavaScript using Babel and Webpack

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6

I want to use babel and webpack to compile ES6 to javascript.

This is my current `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports={
    entry: './src/app.js',
    output: {
        path: __dirname +'./dist',
        filename: 'app.bundle.js'
    }
}
```

Everything sounds ok after running the webpack command in cmd but the bundle.js file isn't in the dist folder.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add the [babel-loader](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader) to the list of module loaders that your code uses(and to your project dependencies).

Then, you would need to add it to the list of loaders that Webpack executes.

For example, following the babel-loader documentation:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

In particular, preset-env replaces the previous latest, es2017 es2016, es2015 presets, as you can see in [the docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/#presets).